# Apache rewrite rule and cookie set

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

Given a URL like: http://www.company.com/somepage?email=john.doe@organization.org

I'd like to do the following:

1) Rewrite the request to http://www.company.com/somepage (without a query string)
2) Set an EMAIL cookie on the response whose value is 'john.doe@organization.org'

(How) could this be configured in httpd.conf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Should be solved by something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} email=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/somepage?.*$ http://www.company.com/somepage? [R,L,CO=EMAILCookie:%1:www.company.com:43200]
```